# Can't embed a icon into a button

Tags: python, button, icons, imagebutton, python-3.3

Firstly I would like to start. I am a newbie to Python, and before posting a question I have done extensive research and trial and error through the various previous postings.

Ideally, I am attempting to create a small tkinter frame with a label defining the frames details and three buttons. The buttons and labels work and the placement went well. Its when I attempt to add an Icon into the button that it throws me and error.

This is the script so far:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def doNothing():
    print("doNothing")

icon1=PhotoImage(file="icon1.png")
icon2=PhotoImage(file="icon2.png")
icon3=PhotoImage(file="icon3.png")

W=tkinter.Tk()
W.geometry("325x300+0+0")
W.configure(bg="gray10")

FRAME1=Frame(W, width=100, height =100)
FRAME1.place(x=0,y=0)
LABEL1=Label(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, text="Profile",font="Verdana 10 bold",width=25, height =1).grid(row=0, column=0)
Button1= Button(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, width=3, height =1,command=doNothing).grid(row=0, column=1)
Button1.config(image=icon1)
Button1.pack()
Button2= Button(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, width=3, height =1,command=doNothing).grid(row=0, column=2)
Button2.config(image=icon2)
Button2.pack()
Button3= Button(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, width=3, height =1,command=doNothing).grid(row=0, column=3)
Button3.config(image=icon3)
Button3.pack()

W.mainloop()
```

When I run this script, I get the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ADRIA/PycharmProjects/LATAM/TESTING CODE.py", line 7, in <module>
icon1=PhotoImage(file="icon1.png")
  File "C:\Users\ADRIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3394, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ADRIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3335, in __init__
raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
```

Any assistance to clear this up would be amazing.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to create the `PhotoImage` before having created the `Tk` instance. Which is what the error is trying to tell you with `Too early to create image`.

Simply switch this around:

```
icon1=PhotoImage(file="icon1.png")
icon2=PhotoImage(file="icon2.png")
icon3=PhotoImage(file="icon3.png")

W=tkinter.Tk()
```

So `tkinter.Tk()` comes first like this:

```
W=tkinter.Tk()

icon1=PhotoImage(file="icon1.png")
icon2=PhotoImage(file="icon2.png")
icon3=PhotoImage(file="icon3.png")
```

The other problem you're getting is because you assign `Button1` like this:

```
Button1= Button(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, width=3, height =1,command=doNothing).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

You aren't assigning the `Button` instance to `Button1` what you're actually assigning it the return value of `.grid(row=0, column=1)`.

What you need to do is change:

```
Button1= Button(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, width=3, height =1,command=doNothing).grid(row=0, column=1)
Button1.config(image=icon1)
```

Into:

```
Button1= Button(FRAME1,relief=FLAT, width=3, height =1,command=doNothing)
Button1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button1.config(image=icon1)
```

You must also do this but `Button2` and `Button3`.

Additionally [never mix grid and pack](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

> Warning: Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution that both managers are happy with. Instead of waiting, kill the application, and take another look at your code. A common mistake is to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.

So if you want to use `Button*.grid()` then you have to remove the `Button.pack()` calls.

Comment: So I've made the alteration to the script. However the output is now:                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ADRIA/PycharmProjects/LATAM /TESTING CODE.py", line 19, in <module>
    Button1.config(image=icon1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Do I have to reformat the PNG's to ICOs or GIF? Or have I made a rookie mistake?

Comment: You sir are amazing that cleared up literally two hours of back-and-forth in alterations and research.